# Why simple factorization of semisimple modules is unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, noncommutative-algebra, direct-sum, semi-simple-rings

The Ring $A$ is commutative or not. I'm trying to understand the proof of the theorem of unicity of simple factorization of semisimple modules. I already know Shur's lemma, and  that, as a corollary of isomorphism theorems of direct sum and product of  modules, we have $$
\operatorname{Hom_A}(M_\alpha, \bigoplus_{B \in B}\Lambda_{\beta} N_{\beta}) \cong \bigoplus_{B \in B}\Lambda_{\beta}\left(M_\alpha, N_{\beta}\right)$$ but I can't understand why if we have $M_\alpha \cong N_\beta$ (isomorphism) then $$
\operatorname{Hom_A}(M_\alpha, \bigoplus_{B \in B}\Lambda_{\beta} N_{\beta}) \cong \Lambda_{\beta} \left(M_\alpha, N_{\beta}\right)$$ for a unique $\beta$.
I have two questions:

1. why they omitted the direct sum?
2. why this is true for a unique $\beta$.

Please click here to see the picture:
[The theorem and the begining of the proof with the difficulty highlited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhmE5.png)

And click please here for [the notation used in the theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhsfa.png)

Comment: I guess they tacitly assume that $N_\beta \not \simeq N_{\beta'}$ for $\beta \neq \beta'$, although that is not clearly stated (and not necessarily true). Looks a bit odd indeed.

Comment: Do you know the lemma of Schur?

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Álvarez Yes I know the shur's lemma, and I don't any problem with the ditinction tha the proof made, I only have a problem with the hilighted passage in the picture.

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg Yes they are different. I will edit the post and add the notation used in the theorem right now, as a picture . thank you.

Comment: What do the $\Lambda_\beta$ symbols stand for? Are they natural numbers counting multiplicities of given simple submodules $N_\beta$? Like this?
$$
\Lambda_\beta N_\beta = \underbrace{N_\beta \oplus \cdots \oplus N_\beta}_{\Lambda_\beta}
$$

Comment: @SammyBlack  yes exactly. you can see the last picture for more details about notations. Your statement is correct, it's the sum of M_\beta "\Lambda \beta times", Lambda can be infinite set of indexes.

Comment: @SammyBlack But not natural numbers, it can be infinite too

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that $M_\alpha$ can't be isomorphic to more than one $N_\beta$ because $N_\beta$s are pairwise distincts.
Ans by shur's lemma, we can conslude that the other homomorphism will be trivial, beacause of the simplicity of the modules.